# How can I translate main menu navigation for multiple languages?

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, language, multiple

I'm trying to translate the Main Menu into different languages but I can't figure out how this is done since all the translate I have done has been done through static blocks.
The main menu shown below with the links needed to be translated to with red arrows are not a static block.
This menu includes home and the option to add whichever "categories" you create as links to this main menu.
Any help?  would be greatly appreciated
[image]

here is the page incase code needs to be inspected: https://fixlcdscreens.com/italian/

Answer (score 2):

Does your main menu names are coming from your categories? if **yes**, you can give different names to each category according to the store language.

[image]